# To make substitles for audio in OSX

Tags: audio, subtitle

I have many recordings where I want English subtitles.
However, those subtitles do not exist. 
So it would be great to have some application which could pick up some words and make a raw subtitle.

**Is there any good software to make subtitles from recordings in OSX?**

Answer (score 1):

[Video Lan Client](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) can play just about every format of subtitle that's out there.

Comment: Sorry, I made my question clearer. I want to make subtitles from recordings which do not have subtitles.